# Сайт на Wordpress. Как удалить файлы cookie, созданные плагином Autoptimize, желательно выборочно. Чтобы посетитель не видел их во всплывающем окне

Tags: wordpress, cookie

```
cookielawinfo-checkbox-advertisement 
chaini-domik.ru 
HTTP 
1 year 
First found URL: https://chaini-domik.ru/statii/ 
Cookie purpose description: Used to detect if the visitor has accepted the marketing category in the cookie banner. This cookie is necessary for GDPR-compliance of the website. 
Initiator: Script tag, page source line number 68
Source: https://chaini-domik.ru/wp-content/cache/autoptimize/js/autoptimize_d2b1450aab8bb17af2507c7cc794cd98.js 
Data is sent to: Russia (not adequate)
```

Cookie bot прислал данный отчет.

Answer (score 0):

Куки выставляет не Autoptimize, а плагин GDPR Cookie Consent. Autooptimize лишь объединяет скрипты, потому и сообщение указывает на него.

Зайдите на страницу `/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=cookielawinfo` на своём сайте и удалите ненужные вам куки.

Comment: Вау, в кои веки мне минус поставили. Ну, come on, красавец, поясни, за что.